# I am getting an error when creating a new react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

[Erorr message while creating a new React App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkDT4.png)

Comment: Please provide a bit more information within your post so it will be easier for community to help you. For example it will be interesting to know your environment, commands you run, etc.

Comment: I think that you should start with reading the docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html

Answer (score 1):

You are not creating a new react app, you are installing the npm module, which already exists. You need to run `npx create-react-app my-app`
[See more](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html)

Comment: I tried to run the command npx-create-react-app my-app but it gives me another error. 

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:968
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\user1\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\index.js'
←[90m    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:965:15)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:841:27)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)←[39m
←[90m    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47←[39m {

Answer (score 0):

It says the file already exists so try to create it in another folder and see if it will be fixed.